# angularjs $window object null when running on Linux

Tags: angularjs, linux

I'm not sure if this is something I'm doing wrong, or if it's just not supported on Linux but I have a controller that works when I run it on a Windows machine, but fails on Linux. I've traced it to this method:

```
$scope.displayHtmlPage = function(key) {
    $scope.loadHtmlPage(key).then(function(data) {
    w = $window.open();
    w.document.write(data);
    w.document.close();
    });
};
```

The html page gets loaded fine, and on Windows, it then opens a tab and displays it. On Linux it fails because on this line:

```
    w = $window.open();
```

The var 'w' is ending up as null. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: `null` is a valid return value when the browser does not allow the window to open.

Comment: Understood (and thanks) - however, I have the server running on two different machines, one Windows, one Linux. On my browser (which is on a windows machine) I have two tabs open, one to the server on the windows machine, one to the server on the linux machine.  In the same browser, it opens the window fine when pointed at the Windows-based server, but when I do the same thing with the Linux-based server, the window fails to open.  Do you know why the same browser would allow the window to open in one instance but not the other?

Answer (score 2):

I am very sorry about this - it was the pop-up blocker (I totally should have seen that).  It was blocking for one server but not the other. Nothing to see here, please carry on!